# How is WebAssembly cross-platform when Assembly is not?

Tags: assembly, webassembly

### My understanding

- WebAssembly is like Assembly, except that

  - it runs cross-platform
  - it runs isolated
  - it runs on browsers
- But how is WASM *fast* and cross-platform simultaneously?

  - Does it pack multiple precompiled binary executables for multiple CPU vendors, like Apple's Universal Binary?
  - But then whenever a new type of CPU gets announced, they wouldn't be able to run existing WASMs
- WebAssembly's runtime environments (RE) are low-level virtual stack machines (akin to JVM or Flash VM)
- Seems like WASM is closer to intermediate Java Byte Code instead of the genuinely low-level Assembly.

  - But then, why is it faster?
  - JS Interpreter can skip the parsing
  - It can ship in a much more compact file format

Now my questions.

### Question

- Is WASM only creating intermediate bytecodes from existing C/C++/Rust codes, just like Java JVM, not compiling to bare metal?
- What is the relationship between WebAssembly and Assembly?
- Does WASM borrow any idea, technology, or philosophy from Assembly?

Comment: Same way Java bytecode or LLVM-IR is cross-platform when machine code for a real CPU is not.  It's input for a JIT compiler that targets whatever real CPU.

Comment: Really wish people would stop calling LLVM IR "cross-platform". (The same C code compiles to different LLVM IR on different CPUs or OSes because of calling convention differences at a minimum, even ignoring differences in C system headers.)

Comment: @NickLewycky IR is cross-platform in the sense that it was designed to be an abstraction layer that can be easily converted to machine code. It's up to the upper layers to keep compatibility across platforms if such a thing is needed.

Comment: People hear "LLVM IR is cross-platform" and think it means that there is no difference in LLVM IR that runs on x86-64 Windows and ARM Linux. Eventually people would hit a case that doesn't work, ask for help, and discover that LLVM is portable in the sense that you may create different IR for different platforms, at which point their response would indicate that they felt lied to about portability in the first place. I really wish people would stop calling LLVM IR cross-platform. Obviously there's a large subset that is, but not function calls or intrinsics, any large "real-world" code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an approximation, you can think of WebAssembly as defining its own CPU with its own instructions. It has its own binary encoding, so "0x6A" means "pop two i32's from the top of the stack and add them, push the result on the top of the stack". You can read the full spec: https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/bikeshed/

"Why is it faster" is a complex issue, the short answer is that it was "well designed" by people who have a deep understanding of contemporary compiler technology and CPU design. When your browser receives WebAssembly it could interpret it one instruction at a time, but WAsm was designed so that you could compile it into native code quickly and get reasonably fast native CPU code.

> Is WASM only creating intermediate bytecodes from existing C/C++/Rust codes, just like Java JVM, not compiling to bare metal?

It does not contain precompiled binaries for any particular real CPU.

> What is the relationship between WebAssembly and Assembly?

A CPU only knows how to run instructions in its own assembly language, the "instruction set architecture". Therefore all other software must be converted to this first (or run through an interpreter which is itself a program that is converted to CPU instructions first). WebAssembly was designed to make the conversion to native assembly on real machines like x86, ARM and RISC-V easy.

The relationship is that WAsm must be converted to CPU assembly, or run in an interpreter. Also, WebAssembly is enough like a real CPU that compilers which can already emit code for different CPUs could be extended to emit code for WAsm. This is why we can compile C and Rust to WebAssembly. It's reasonable to expect that any new programming language which can be compiled for a real CPU could also be compiled for WAsm.

> Does WASM borrow any idea, technology, or philosophy from Assembly?

Sure. Assembly is an imperative programming language (instructions run one after the other), and so too with WAsm. Many actual CPUs define a notion of a stack that you can push/pop and WAsm uses a stack. Most CPUs have instructions like "add two 32-bit integers", and so does WAsm. Most CPUs have "branch" instructions, and so does "WAsm". Most CPUs have instructions to read and write memory at given byte addresses, and so does WAsm.

Comment: "The relationship is that WAsm must be converted to CPU assembly, or run in an interpreter." This is true for almost all languages. JS can be compiled and run in an interpreted. So does x86 assembly. Also, we can compile C e Rust to WASM because we already have a front-end that compiles them to an intermediate register language (e.g. llvm IR) and that takes care of the complex part. We can easily translate the IR to C as well, which is a high-level language. Or Java. Finally, the WASM stack is not really like a real CPU stack and ditto for the control instructions.

Comment: I was intentionally pointing out similarities because the question asked for them, but yes, 100%. For instance "add" on most CPUs works between two registers, not the stack. WAsm is odd that way. Branch in WAsm must be provably structured control flow, while it's arbitrary in most CPUs. Translating C to Java is different from compiling C to Assembly, you end up creating a "C environment" in Java and compiling to that, going up in levels of abstraction instead of down.

Answer (score 5):

WASM is a *specific* purpose assembly.
It's also a collective effort that is not driven by market laws.

If WASM will really take hold and the popularity of a browser will depend on it, then *surely* some browser will add vendor extensions to it, just like it already happened with JS and CSS. Making WASM not so cross-platform.

It's not a technical issue, it's a human one. We can easily design compatible CPUs but we prefer to design *fast* CPUs and everybody has their own idea on how to design a fast CPU.

---

WASM is interpreted by the browser, most likely JITted. It doesn't need any external library, it's not a general-purpose assembly. It's made to be run in a browser.

It's faster because it's already compiled to simple instructions, just look at the specification for WASM and for ECMAScript (JS) and you can easily see how much more work is to parse, compile and execute JS w.r.t. simpler low-level instructions.
That's why it's called WASM, because it's a set of low-level instructions compared to JS.
But besides being lower-level, it shares *nothing* (but a few concepts, like SIMD) with a conventional assembly language. When compared with a real assembly language WASM is way too high level.

You can convince yourself by looking at any assembly and at the WASM specification. You won't find structured instructions or the concept of a module or of unreachable code in a conventional assembly language.
It's *clearly* designed with a specific abstract machine that would be expensive to implement in hardware.